# Click deeplink from FB Post and FB Messenger not redirecting to my app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, deep-linking, facebook-messenger

I am using Deep link feature in my one application. I have integrated and it was working fine in my application.

While testing in deep with different server, i am getting one issue with open my application from link from **Facebook** and **Facebook Messenger**.

Below is my code in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.DeepLinkActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">

    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data
            android:host="myfirstlink.com"
            android:scheme="https" />

        <data
            android:host="mysecondlink.com"
            android:scheme="https" />

    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Everything is working fine in my local server but if i change my local server with live server then i am getting some issues with open app directly with shared link.

Below are my detailed information where i am getting issues with facebook deeplinking.

**With My Local Server:**

- *Facebook Wall Post:*

Click on shared post using Intent: Opens My App inside FB InApp Browser. If i click on three dots (Context menu), then it asks to open with My App.

Click on shared post using Link Manually: Opens My App directly (It's Fine - Working)

- *Facebook Messenger:*

Click on shared post using Intent: Asks to Open with MyApp (It's Fine - Working)

Click on shared post using Link Manually: Opens My App directly (It's Fine - Working)

**With My Live Server:**

- *Facebook Wall Post:*

Click on shared post using Intent: Opens My App inside FB InApp Browser. If i click on three dots (Context menu), then it asks to open with My App.

Click on shared post using Link Manually: It Opens Playstore. - ***It should not Happen***

- *Facebook Messenger:*

Click on shared post using Intent: Asks to Open with MyApp (It's Fine - Working)

Click on shared post using Link Manually: It Opens Playstore. - ***It should not Happen***

I did lot research on the Google as well as checked Facebook documentation about the deep linking. But i didn't get much information to fix this issue in my app.

Also i have mentioned `android:autoVerify="true"` in my intent-filter inside Activity but still if i click on deeplink then it's asking to choose app to open.

Can anyone help to guide me How can i fix this issue?

Right now getting the same issue with `Deeplink` with `Facebook` in iOS application as well.

Thank you

Comment: I am also getting same error in my iOS application. Facebook is not redirecting to my application when I try to click any `deeplink` from `Facebook`. Let me know if you get any solution for it.